# ssrs export to pdf creates whitespace

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I am having major page break issues when exporting from SSRs (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder) to PDF. The preview is showing the report working perfectly, but when exported, it creates major page break issues (creates white space in the reports).

I have tried removing all page breaks, ensuring my page size Is small enough, changing interactive height to 0, setting ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to 'True' and any other combination of things I could think of with no luck.

I would love some help if possible.

The report is a tablix report, and it is moving a sub-table (not subreport) to the next page.

Comment: This is a frustrating exercise that I can relate to!  It sounds like you are on the right track, but have you tried tweaking with your page margins and confirming that your page size is indeed small enough?

Comment: The thing that always comes to mind is what Daniel said too.  Margins combined with page size or some item in the report is extending past what you think it would so it prints strange.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that can cause this and I'll try to remember all of them.

First, right click the area outside of your report and go to the report properties. Make note of your margins.

Next look at the size of your page content. You want the width of everything to be less than your page size minus margins. For a standard page of 8.5 inches wide and the default 1" margins, your content should be LESS than 6.5. If you're right at 6.5 that's going to be enough to content onto another page.

The other thing I've learned is that SSRS tends to want to render ALL whitespace. Try removing all whitespace between your content ESPECIALLY at the end of the report. If that ends up being your problem, you'll have to experiment with adding back whitespace. Sometimes it seems like SSRS tries to render whitespace and it's too much to fit on the current page, so it puts it on another page. Then the next content is too big to fit on that page so it will go to the next page. If that's the case your best bet might be to add an invisible row at the end of your table to create whitespace.

All of this whitespace rendering applies to horizontal as well. Make you make the width of your report in the designer less than the width you can fit on the page. You can test this by making your content and page width drastically thinner and seeing if you still get the blank pages.

A lot of those fancy FillAllWhitespace or whatever flags don't work. That includes the repeat the headers on next row and scroll header with table checkboxes in the table.

It's a finicky little software but you can do amazing things with it. Once you figure out all of the weird stuff.